# Retrieve the total number with javascript in json

Tags: javascript, json, facebook

Hey guys am developing an app in javascript.i used a property in my app like `thread.comments.data[j].message;` which succcesfuly receives the messages like

http://pastebin.com/x774y222

What i need is to find the total number of messages send in words.
The javascript code am using is http://pastebin.com/7dQVMJga.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: try `thread.comments.data[j].length;` if you want 3, I didn't get what do you mean by *the total of these 3 numbers*.

Comment: @Mritunjay i mean thread.comments.data[j].message.length .and it returns 3 number ..what i need is to find the sum of 3 numbers

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle illustrating the problem?

Comment: I've added an answer,

Comment: @JonathanCrowe actually am using fb api ..and the thread.comments.data[j].message.length; returns the messages like something something something ...What i need is to find the total number of messages

Comment: can you paste the console output of thread.comments.data?

Comment: This is the output http://pastebin.com/x774y222  what i need is to add all these strings and find its number

Answer (score 1):

just send it through a function that calculates the length:

```
var total = getTotalLength(thread.comments.data);
function getTotalLength(arr) {
   var total = 0;
   for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
      total += arr[i].message.length;
   }
   return total;
)
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: i mean thread.comments.data[j].message.length .and it returns 3 number ..what i need is to find the sum of 3 numbers

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sum this numbers, just use one for loop..

```
var total = 0;

for(var i=0;i<thread.comments.data.length;i++){
total+=thread.comments.data[i].message.length;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it is an array property, you can define a prototype method in order to get the sum of the property values

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NzC8y/)

Code Snippet:

```
Array.prototype.sum = function (prop) {
    var total = 0
    for ( var i = 0, _len = this.length; i < _len; i++ ) {
        total += this[i][prop].length
    }
    return total
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you

```
var total = thread.comments.data.reduce(function(first,second){
   return first+second.message.length
},0)
```

Comment: this is not i want ..i want to count the total of words ..like a word a word ..the output must be 4

Comment: @user3886467 can you update your question properly what do you want.